# Excel VBA: How do I refer to a Form Control, on a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I've added two Dropdown (aka ComboBox) to a Sheet
[image]

Starting from this question ([How do I refer to a controls object, on a worksheet, using a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919797/how-do-i-refer-to-a-controls-object-on-a-worksheet-using-a-variable-name)) I tried the following experiment without succeding.

[image]

How do I access to the controls on an Excel Sheet? And where do I see the name / properties of the controls I have just inserted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()

    Dim s As Object
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    Debug.Print s.ControlFormat.Value

End Sub
```

`Application.Caller` contains the name of the shape "containing" the form control

Similarly you can access other controls by name:

```
Dim myName as String, c As Object
myName = "List Box 2"
Set c = ActiveSheet.Shapes(myName).ControlFormat
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding it like that I suggest creating a Shape variable, and use that to add data/properties.

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17677080/4650297):

```
Sub t()
Dim newDD As Shape

Set newDD = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(1, 1).Left, Top:=Cells(2, 1).Top, Width:=100, Height:=20)
 With newDD
        .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 2
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "Item 1", 1
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "item 2", 2
        .Name = "New Combo Box"
        .OnAction = "myCombo_Change"
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is something similar to the code behind in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Dim checkBox1 As Object
Set checkBox1 = Sheet1.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object
MsgBox checkBox1.Value
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27931341)

Comment: The biggest problem is that the question was about form controls, but this answer is about Ole controls